# Mail from external machines to root mail box of linux host

Tags: linux, windows, email, root

I have a quick simple question I could not find a quick answer in the internet.
Is it possible to use a Windows machine to send an e-mail from a virus tool to a Linux root mail account.

example: Windows with ClamWIN send mail on alert, to Linux system to get on root@localhost so that root on the linux machine can read it into a dashboard?

as in mail address something like: root@1.2.3.4 (ip) as destination...?

When I search for mail to linux machine I only get results for setting up a mail server to use for all kinds of purposes, but i just want it simple to the root mail box of all linux machines that already by default exists.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: 1) set up linux host to receive mail send to @hostname.local 2) have AV software sendmail to root@hostname.local, provided AV host resolv hostname.local to hostname's IP. Hard part is setting linux to receive mail IMO, tcp connectivity and name resolution is easy.

Answer (score 0):

1. Many SMTP server accept addresses `root@[1.2.3.4]`
2. email for root **SHOULD** be redirected (e.g. via email aliases) to non provileged OS account/mailbox
   AFAIK it is implemented on **almost** all unix/linux installations
3. On may unix/linux "workstations" SMTP server accepts incoming SMTP connections only on 127.0.0.1 (loopback) TCP/IP interface => it **does not** accept smtp connections from outside/other hosts

Comment: ok that is usefull, thanks, I'll keep in mind to create a user like clamav on the reciever side and send mail to that instead of root. But basically I need to enable incoming smtp connections over tcp/ip from external. (perhaps specific subnets).